# is there anyway to check what videos or images has been shared from my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, video, sharing, logs

is there any thing like logs to see and check what videos and images has been shared from my iPhone to social media and private massaging apps like WhatsApp or messenger?

Answer (score 1):

No, you’ll need a forensic specialist to image the device and prepare a report for that level of detail.

What you can do is restrict these apps from ever accessing those data sources and manage the device closely with app locks and the existing privacy controls.